# Docker swarm UCP issues : no route host randomly between containers

Tags: docker, swarm, docker-ucp

We are using docker swarm UCP (Mirantis) as an orchestrator for our containers, we have 10 nodes (Redhat 8) on our cluster to server more than 130 docker service (700 container), we have also a huge number of bridge networks to limit access between containers for security raisons, sometimes randomly container can't communicate with each others due to `No route to Host` error, sometimes we restart the client and the server container to resolve this issue but it's not the case for all times, we switched LB mode From `VIP` to `DNSRR` but we still have the same issues sometimes, sometimes when we ping to a docker service we got a wrong IP adresse, did you ever have this issues and how to debug to resolve it.

Comment: We would also know if this issue come from iptables updates which are incorrect in some cluster worker nodes